# How to get a QProgressBar in QT with rounded edges and rounded progress edges?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qprogressbar

I have created a vertical progress bar and an trying to style it with rounded edges. No matter what I do, I don't seem to be able to get the progress or chunk of the progress bar (QProgressBar::chunk) with rounded edges. Please help me out, I am new to QT.

Please find my code below:-

```
progressbar_V = new QProgressBar;
progressbar_V->setParent(this);
progressbar_V->setMinimum(0);
progressbar_V->setMaximum(5);
progressbar_V->setValue(3);
progressbar_V->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar{ border: solid grey; border-width: 6; border-radius: 12; color: black; text-align: centre; margin-right: 12; }, QProgressBar::chunk:vertical {background-color: #05B8CC; width: 20px;}");
progressbar_V->setGeometry(250,250,60,300);
progressbar_V->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);
```

The Progress Bar text is at the top in the output as well. How will I get it to the middle of the vertical progress bar

Comment: text-align: centre; --> text-align: center;

Comment: Not sure if this will fix anything, but you have a comma in your stylesheet: `, QProgressBar::chunk:vertical {...`. Remove that comma.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you can use this parameter:

```css
border-radius: 50px;
```

to get round borders !
*but you just forgotten to specify **px** at the end*

So, once your code is updated, it looks like this :

```css
progressbar_V->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar{ border: solid grey; border-width: 6; border-radius: 12px; color: black; text-align: centre; margin-right: 12; }, QProgressBar::chunk:vertical {background-color: #05B8CC; width: 20px;}");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your style sheet into something like this:

> progressbar_V->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar{ border: solid grey;border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;border-bottom-left-radius: 12px; color: black; text-align: centre; },QProgressBar::chunk {background-color: #05B8CC;border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;}");

happy coding..